# How to adjust the image according to searched item in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I ma using a UISearch bar to filter the lists in table, Every thing works fine but the problem in correct image is not shown according to text...Please see below images. Any help will be appriciated...
[image: Initial image before search]

[image: After Search]

```
  -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {



    if(searchText.length == 0)
    {
        _isFiltered = FALSE;
    }
    else{
        // NSPredicate *resultPredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF.name contains[cd] %@)or(SELF.rank contains[cd] %@)or(SELF.score contains[cd] %@)",searchText,searchText,searchText];
        NSPredicate *resultPredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF contains[cd] %@)",searchText];
        self.filteredTableData = [self.searchItemsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
        NSLog(@"Predicated array %@", self.filteredTableData);
        self.isFiltered = YES;
        if (self.filteredTableData.count == 0) {
            [[CLAlertHandler standardAlertHandler]showAlert:@"No match found!" title:AppName];
        }
    }
    //[self.searchTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.searchTableView reloadData];
}


    (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    SearchTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if(cell == nil)
        cell = [[SearchTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (_isFiltered) {
        cell.itemNameLabel.text = [self.filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.iconImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.searchImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    else
    {
    cell.itemNameLabel.text = [self.searchItemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.iconImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.searchImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What's the code of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and the filtering? My guess is that's you're using a NSArray for images, and a NSArray for text, so if you filter only the text NSArray, your images will be not synchronized with the changes.

Comment: yess and the code is NSPredicate *resultPredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF contains[cd] %@)",searchText];
        self.filteredTableData = [self.searchItemsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

Comment: Please edit your question with your code, and also the code of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: check this link it might help you: http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/

Answer (score 1):

```
if (_isFiltered) {
    ...
    cell.iconImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.searchImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
else
{
    ...
    cell.iconImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.searchImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

What is the point in the if clause when you execute the same code in both branches? I'd say that you schould do something different in the if and the else branch. E.g. fetch another name of the image from another array or so.

Something like

```
if (_isFiltered) {
    cell.itemNameLabel.text = [self.filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.iconImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.filteredImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
else
{
    cell.itemNameLabel.text = [self.searchItemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.iconImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.searchImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

Comment: how to filter the images using NSPredicate??

Comment: Hmmm... you can't. You could create a new class made of image and text and build the searchItemsArray upon that. This is what i would do because it is generally not a good idea having two arrays with correlating indexes.

Comment: Alternatively you fetch the string object from `filteredTableData` with `objectAtIndex` and then you search for this object in `searchitemsArray` using the `indexOfObject` method of `NSArray` which gives you the index that you can use on `searchImagesArray` to get the image.